# Cocos2d 2.0 black screen ccscene

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

Im having a big trouble with Cocos2d 2.0 version =(

the problem: after launch the app, my gamescene doesnt go up the screen, there is a hell black screen, whatever I do.

Here go a stretch from my code.

I`ll appreciate if you guys try to help me =D
Thanks!

```
//AppDelegate from cocos2d basic template, I change this line
[director_ pushScene:[GameScene node]];

//my GameScene class implementation
- (id)init
{
   if(self != nil)
    {
        BackgroundLayer *backgroundLayer = [BackgroundLayer node];
        [self addChild:backgroundLayer z:0];
    }

    return self;
}

//then, my BackgroundLayer class implementation
- (id)init
{
    if(self != nil)
    {
        CCSprite *backgroundImage = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"backgroundiPhone.png"];

        CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
        [backgroundImage setPosition:CGPointMake(screenSize.width / 2, screenSize.height / 2)];
        //yea the image is in the project, maybe if I add some color at the sprite to be sure?

        [self addChild:backgroundImage z:0 tag:0];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you call parent's `init` inside your `init` method? Add this line to the beginning of your init method.

```
self = [super init];
```